# how to send different outout to multiple terminal on the same machine

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

I want to be able to run my Python scripts in one terminal but to print the useful output to another terminal on the same machine. Having the ability to refresh the terminal with the useful output would also be good because then the useful out can be built up incrementally as though its printing out. How can I do this?

I have googled this but most answers relate to using things like 'write' and 'talk'. With 'write' I can send messages to another terminal but there isn’t much control over which window or refreshing/clearing the screen. I am using Ubuntu Trusty Tahr

Comment: While not *exactly* the same, the answers on the question now linked to from the top of yours should explain everything you need. Basically, you'd just manually write to a different `/dev/pts/...` device. If that doesn't answer your problem, let me know.

Comment: Clearing is just a matter of [sending the right characters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5367075/12870).

Comment: yes that work and i can clear simply by send the 'clear' command to the second terminal. live long and prosper ;)